# Java hibernate save objects in different schemas which are in one database

Tags: java, hibernate, schema, database-schema, hibernate-mapping

I am using DB2 database and hibernate framework. There are two tables such as Word and Litter and their relationship is one to many.

1. Schema A:

   ```
   Table Word: ID,
   IDLIT -> references to ID of Litter table
   Name
   ```
2. Schema B:

   ```
   Table Litter ID,
   Short_Name,
   Long_Name.
   ```

Both tables are located in two different schemas but in one database. I have an POJO and XML mapping files to map the tables. Now how can I save the objects into database while handling the many to one relationship(Litter - Word)? Is the any suggestion? If yes please provide me with detailed instructions, thanks in advance!

### Updated question

Also I have changed because my mapping xml files different for each POJO class. Here is the code for running:

```
 Session session = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   session.beginTransaction();

   Word word = new Word();
   Word word1 =new Word();

   Litter litter = new Litter();
   litter.setFullname("bla bla");
   word.setLitter(litter);    
   word1.setLitter(litter); //Here I have to handle one to many relationship

   Set Words =new  HashSet();
   Words.add(word);
   Words.add(word1);
   litter.setWords(words);
   session.save(litter);
   session.save(word);
   session.save(word1);
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  session.close();
```

But this code giving an exception: JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions 
Is the approach which I am using is correct?

```
Stack trace------------------
INFO: schema update complete
Hibernate: select max(ID) from LITTER
сен 25, 2012 7:33:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: -204, SQLState: 42704
сен 25, 2012 7:33:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=BIMASH.LITTER, DRIVER=3.64.104
сен 25, 2012 7:33:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: -204, SQLState: 42704
сен 25, 2012 7:33:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=BIMASH.LITTER, DRIVER=3.64.104
сен 25, 2012 7:33:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: -727, SQLState: 56098
сен 25, 2012 7:33:42 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-204;42704;BIMASH.LITTER, DRIVER=3.64.104
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.getNext(IncrementGenerator.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.generate(IncrementGenerator.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant part of the stack trace and the mapping of the association?

Comment: <hibernate-mapping >
    <class name="pojopackage.Word" table="Word" schema ="A" > </class></hibernate-mapping> <hibernate-mapping >
    <class name="pojopackage.Litter" table="Litter" schema ="B" ></class> </hibernate-mapping> how can i display <> tags in the question area?

Comment: just use the tags in code snippets. Surround them with ` or just select and click `code sample`. See [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the schema a mapped class belongs to with the `schema` attribute of the `<class>` element in the mapping file. Notice this will override the setting in the general `<hibernate-mapping>`'s `schema` attribute.

```
<!-- A is set to be the default schema -->
<hibernate-mapping schema="A">
    <class name="mypackage.Word" table="WORD" >
    ....
    </class>

    <!-- Overriding the schema definition for this class -->
    <class name="mypackage.Litter" table="LITTER" schema="B">
    ....
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The following Hibernate reference chapter might be worth a read: [Chapter 5. Basic O/R Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html), specially the sections about the `<hibernate-mapping>` and `<class>` elements.

### UPDATE

Seeing the stack trace, it seems that a `<generator class="increment">` is being used in the class. If it's the case (it seems so by the `select max(ID) from LITTER` query), you'll also have to specify the schema in the `<generator>` so that the issued query transforms into `select max(ID) from B.LITTER`. You can achieve that with a `<param>` named `schema` in the `<generator>`:

```
<generator class="increment">
    <param name="schema">B</param>
</generator>
```

For more details see this almost duplicate question: [Hibernate: ID generator using increment and Oracle Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1566263/851811)

Comment: I am new to hibernate, therefore should I create two hibernate.cfg.xml? I have created classes through reverse engineering which I have two file Word.java and Word.hbm.xml and Iam using Netbeans. What else files should I change?

Comment: If you've used Hibernate Tools to do the reverse engineering, you can specify which schemas to reverse engineer with the [`<schema-selection>`](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#d0e5234) option in the `hibernate.reveng.xml` file. Alternatively, just use the `schema` attribute in the `<hibernate-mapping>` or `<class>` tag of the Entity that is not in the default schema.

Comment: i am grateful for your effort, I have changed schema for hibernate-mapping tag of Word, but its giving an exception, i have updated the question. Can you have a look?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `schema` attribute in the `<class>` element instead?

Comment: yeap, I have putted 'schema' attribute in the '<class>' element. Here the another exception: SQLGrammarException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator

Comment: I've updated the answer. Seems like you need to also specify the `schema` in a `<generator>`.

Comment: Xavi, I have followed your instruction, the Litter class inserting normally, while Word class throwing exception SQL Error -530, (database is DB2). Seems, Word class fialing to update Foreign key which is references the Litter. What can be cause? (Thank u very much!)

Comment: Thanks Xavi, i have solved it, the problem was that i had two copy of Litter table, one is in schema A and in schema B, so i have deleted one, so its working properly. i am very grateful for your effort!