# Why is Hibernate generating this SQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate and a MySql server. I use multiple databases as "namespaces" (e.g. `users`, `transactions`, `logging` etc.).

So, I configued Hibernate to NOT connect to a particular database :

`url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/`

The databases where tables are located are defined in the hbm files through the `catalog` attribute :

```
<class name="com.myApp.entities.User" table="user" schema="" catalog="users"> ...
```

When I want to load some data, everything works fine and Hibernate seems to generate the expected SQL queries (by using the catalog prefix in the table names) e.g. :

```
select id from users.user
```

However, when I try to add a new record, Hibernate don't use the `from [catalog].[table_name]` syntax anymore. So I get a MySQL error 'No database selected'.

```
select max(id) from user
```

Hibernate is trying the get the future id to create a new record, but it doesn't specify in which database is located the table, it should be :

```
select max(id) from users.user
```

Why is Hibernate generating this invalid query ? Have someone ever experienced this problem ?

Comment: What's the version of the hibernate you're using?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate-4.2.2

Comment: what happens if you use: schema="users" catalog="users" ?

Comment: @Yori Kusanagi It generates this query : `select id from users.users.user`. If I leave `catalog` empty and I set `schema="users` then it produces exactly the same queries as before.

Comment: Did you set the property hibernate.dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect? Maybe hibernate fails to determine this automatically...

Comment: Are you setting the new id yourself?

Comment: @lunr No I don't, the new id is generated by Hibernate : `<generator class="increment"/>`, I guess this is why Hibernate is trying the execute this query `select max(id) from user` before creating the new record.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566263/hibernate-id-generator-using-increment-and-oracle-schema ?

Comment: @DaDaDom It solved my problem! I didn't know I had to specify the schema for the generator. Thank you very much !

Comment: @DaDaDom, could you please post an answer so I can reward you and mark my question as answered ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the schema for the generator. See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566263/hibernate-id-generator-using-increment-and-oracle-schema) for a more detailed answer.